# Undefined index: on uploading an image into database from php

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for that question, but I tried everything and i can't solve my problem.

I'm trying to add an image to the database from a form in php and then show the image on the page.

However I am with an error I can't solve.

The error is this: `Notice: Undefined index: image in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ test \ index2.php on line 18`

Does anyone could help me please?

Thanks everyone.

-----index.php-----------

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload an image</title>
    </head>   
    <body>

        <form action="index2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             File:
            <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">

        </form>

        <?php
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*****") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database') or die (mysql_error());

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


if (!isset($file)) 
    echo "Please select an image";
else{
   echo $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
   $image_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

   if($image_size==FALSE)
       echo "That's not an image";
   else{
            if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_image(name_image, image) VALUES ('Test','$image' )"))
            echo"Problem uploading image.";
            else
            {
                $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
            echo"Image uploaded.<p />Your Image: <p /><img src=get.php?id=$lastid>";
            }

        }
}
}
?>
```

------get.php-----

```
   <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*****") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database') or die (mysql_error());

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysql_query("select * from table_image where id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;


?>
```

[image]

Line 18: `$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];`

--------------EDIT----------------

thanks everyone for all sugestions.
I tried everything you guys said. And the result was this.

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Remove the echo in `echo $image`

Comment: Well the error, is just a notice.. Meaning there isn't a value for the key you are trying to call..

Comment: Change `if (isset($_POST['image']))` to `if (isset($_FILES['image']))`

Comment: See Daan's answer below. That will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried what he said, and then give me that.

Comment: You're welcome. Then, post a comment under Daan's answer. I think this line `<img src=get.php?idTarefa=$lastid>` would be the issue. Does the file get uploaded though?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the 't' here.

`enctype="mulipart/form-data"`

so

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

You're also trying to check for `isset($_POST['image'])` which should be `isset($_FILES['image'])`

Comment: Good catch. This `if (isset($_POST['image']))` would also be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried what you said, and then give me that error "Problem uploading image."

Comment: You're trying to insert an uploaded file into a column. That won't work. You have to move you're file to a directory on the server with `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: ...or set column as `blob`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- True but I try to avoid it. Actually I never use it.

Comment: I edited the last image of my question. 

a new entry is added to the database, or is successfully made the insertion. 

Those characters appear all but the image don't appear. Why does this happen?

Comment: Because it's encoded if you want to show you're image you have to make a select on the column and echo this: `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_decode($image) .'" />';` presuming you're using a jpeg image.

Comment: Once again thanks for your reply. I'm using a jpeg image. How and where I can use this code: echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_decode($image) .'" />';

Sorry

Comment: After you've made a select statement on the column where the image is stored in.

Comment: The result is the same. I can't understand :(

Answer (score 0):

apart from typo fix of `mulipart/form-data` to `multipart/form-data` You need to validate/check it before accessing

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}
```